# How to view Code Metrics lke Fan-In/Fan-Out with NDepend

Tags: c#, .net, code-metrics, ndepend

I have installed NDepend (14-day trial version) as a Visual Studio 2015 Extension, and it works now.

I would like to get some metrics of some classes in my solution:

- length of identifiers
- fan in / fan out
- weighted method of class
- coupling of class objects

I did not find any useful instruction from its official site, does anyone know?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write [C# LINQ code queries](http://www.ndepend.com/features/cqlinq#CQL) to obtain pretty much any code metric you need.

length of identifiers

```
from t in Application.Types
select new { t, t.SimpleName.Length }
```

fan in / fan out

```
from t in Application.Types
select new { t, t.TypesUsed, t.TypesUsingMe }
```

weighted method of class

```
from t in Application.Types
select new { t, t.CyclomaticComplexity }
```

coupling of class objects (according to [this definition](http://support.objecteering.com/objecteering6.1/help/us/metrics/metrics_in_detail/coupling_between_object_classes.htm))

```
from n in Application.Namespaces
let NumberOfClasses = n.ChildTypes.Count()
let NumberOfLinks = n.ChildTypes.SelectMany(t => t.TypesUsed).Distinct().Count()
select new { n, CBO = NumberOfLinks / (float)NumberOfClasses  }
```

You can then transform a code query into a code rule with the prefix `warnif count > 0` and save the rule to get it executed in Visual Studio and/or in your BuildProcess.

```
// <Name>Type name shouldn't exceed 25 char</Name>
warnif count > 0
from t in Application.Types
where t.SimpleName.Length > 25
orderby t.SimpleName.Length descending
select new { t, t.SimpleName.Length }
```

[image]

Comment: However, I am still exploring NDepend, could you take a look at this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083906/how-to-use-cqlinq-to-get-metrics-of-methods-and-fields-within-a-single-query, it's about the same thing, but I think I had better discuss it in a separate question, thanks.

Comment: In addition, what is the algorithm of Cyclomatic Complexity for methods? Is it the same as described here: http://staff.unak.is/andy/StaticAnalysis0809/metrics/cyclomatic_complexity.html ? I found discrepancy.

Comment: Find all details about NDepend CC here: http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics#CC